# Timestamp in reputation history is a little too wide (in Firefox), causing unnecessary vertical whitespace

Tags: bug, design, firefox, reputation-history

In the latest Firefox (94.0.2) on the latest macOS (Monterey 12.0.1), there is not always enough space to fit the relative timestamp for reputation history events on a single line. The longest possible value, `20 hours ago` is just a little too wide, causing unnecessary vertical whitespace:

[image]

In Safari and Chrome, it fits (but barely so).